# Is it possible to hide a particular application from user?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to create the application that lists all install applications in my device. And After that I want to set it as Hide and Show With which another User can not able to see that particular application.
So is it possible ?
If yes, then How?

Comment: @Blundell. I haven't made such an app myself but why are you so sure a service wouldn't work?

Comment: You can't hide and show applications on a device without basically uninstalling them or rooting the device. Unless you want to re-write your question to be more specific about what you mean by 'hide and show'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you don't add the following in your main activity's declaration in android manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

by doing so, your app will not be listed in launcher but will be installed.
However, in order to run it, perhaps you may register a broadcast receiver in its manifest and use another application to send a broadcast which is received by its (hidden app's) broadcast receiver which starts the activity.

Comment: Yes but he cannot change this on other applications that are installed. Which is what I believed was his question.

Comment: @Waqas: Yes, I want to hide the already installed application also.

Comment: @Waqas: is it possible to comment the LUNCHER code of the other android app during run time ?

Comment: @Waqas: or is it possible to get the icon of the perticular app during run time ? So may be i can relplace that icon with the transperent one and also change the appname with the blank one and get the hide app. Hows that ??

Comment: for that i guess you need to design your own customized Launcher

Answer (score 2):

I implemented something like this but it was added customization in the original android launcher code for a phone. Which allows for modifying the applications that show up in the application's list that is available on the phone. This is only possible if you're working on the baseband software of a phone.

However for your case, you can just remove these declarations:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If its for all the applications, you can create a custom Launcher (ADW Launcher is open source, and provides the source code at https://github.com/AnderWeb/android_packages_apps_Launcher)

Just download it, and you can set whatever apps you want to show in the Launcher.

Another alternative may be, download Go Launcher EX from the Market, and you will be provided with settings to show or hide apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. It is called a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).