# how to hide user interface in android

Tags: android, android-layout, service

I have created a service it runs automatically, I have nothing to do with the interface and I want to hide it. I tried this line in manifest but it hangs my tablet and crashes the app if i click on the app icon.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
```

Comment: Can you share logcat?

Comment: hide interface means activity right? can u post code?

Comment: @random yes i want to hide main activity layout. my activity layout is empty. my app sends gps coordinates after a fixed time and starts automatically on boot. i don't need any layout.

Comment: reffer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8802408/1309629

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't have a layout in your activity then (I'm assuming your activity is launching your service, or else why even have that?).  Have its onCreate launch your service then immediately call finish without calling setContentView.

Answer (score 1):

In Your manifest delete activity and intent filter tags, so your manifest should be like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.arteldev.today"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17"/>

    <application
            android:name=".YourApp"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">


        <service android:name="YourService"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I tried  your answer but now my app is not running. Kindly suggest any other solution. thanks

Comment: How do you know that your app is not running? Check in your device's settings "Running Apps", the service you have should be shown there.